# How do I find the positions of my blobs using pydip?

Tags: python, image-processing, diplib

```
import diplib as dip
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
#reading video
vid = dip.ImageReadICS(r'C:\Users\mrtij\.spyder-py3\20211123_152822_capture.ics')
vid = vid[0:-1, 0:-1, 325:3149]
smvid = dip.Gauss(vid, [2,2,0])

for i in range(1000, 1001):
    img = smvid[0:-1, 0:-1, i]

    imgmask = dip.IsodataThreshold(img)
    imgmask = dip.Label(imgmask)

    measuremnt = dip.MeasurementTool.Measure(imgmask, img)
    print(measurment)
```

I am trying to find positions and sizes of blobs on a relatively low res video, the 20211123_152822_capture.ics file. First I add a smoothing filter and then two masking filters. The MeasurementTool.Measure function however, only returns sizes and not the positions of my blobs. I can't find how to fix this and thought maybe someone here could be of help.
Edit: I only view a single frame here, I plan on saving the coordinates of each blob on each frame, hence the for loop.

Comment: By the way: you are more likely to get an answer here if you use the right tags. Tags is what people filter questions on that they might be able to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, needed to use MeasurementTool.Measure(imgmask, img, ['Size', 'Gravity'])

Comment: “Size” gives you the size of the binary shape, “Mass” gives you the gray-scale “size”, the integral over the Gaussian blob. Likewise, “Center” gives you the centroid of the binary shape, “Gravity” gives you the gray-scale centroid. The gray-scale measurements are typically more precise when measuring Gaussian blobs. You can even grow your labeled image a bit to improve precision ([GrowRegions](https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/regions.html#dip-GrowRegions-dip-Image-CL-dip-Image-CL-dip-Image-L-dip-sint--dip-uint-)).